# Reflecting value of hash in Array Rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, ruby-hash

I have one Array.

```
arr = []
```

I have one Hash

```
hash = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Addind hash in Array

```
arr << hash
```

value of **arr** is:

```
[{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}]
```

Now Adding value in Hash

```
hash[:d] = 4
```

Now See Value of Array is:

```
[{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4}]
```

Can anyone please explain to me about this. as this is a little confusing.
Thank in Advance.

Comment: Adding to `arr` doesn't copy hash and create a new object. It adds the actual `hash` object to `arr`. So any changes to `hash` will affect where ever it sits.

Comment: Assuming that there will be single hash in the arr, following code will serve your purpose:    arr[0].merge!(d: 4)

Comment: Or do not add the hash into the array, instead, add a duplicate to the array: `arr << hash.dup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `hash` inside the array also has the same `object_id`, let's try it with an example

```
2.6.3 :008 > arr = []
 #=> [] 
2.6.3 :009 > hash = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
 #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3} 
2.6.3 :010 > arr << hash
 #=> [{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}] 
2.6.3 :011 > arr.first.object_id
 #=> 70240020878720 
2.6.3 :012 > hash.object_id
 #=> 70240020878720
```

As you can see, `arr.first.object_id` and `hash.object_id` both have same `object_id` therefore any changes you make in `hash` will also be reflected in hash inside `arr` because it's the same object.

Now if you don't want to see that behavior then create a new object instead, use `dup`, try this

```
2.6.3 :001 > arr = []
 #=> [] 
2.6.3 :002 > hash = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
 #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3} 
2.6.3 :003 > arr << hash.dup
 #=> [{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}] 
2.6.3 :004 > arr.first.object_id
 #=> 70094898530860 
2.6.3 :005 > hash.object_id
 #=> 70094898418620 
2.6.3 :006 > hash[:d] = 4
 #=> 4 
2.6.3 :007 > arr
 #=> [{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}] 
2.6.3 :008 > hash
 #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4}
```

`dup` creates a new object and hence you won't see the changes made in both the places because both are different object with different `object_id`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

When we consider enumerable data like `array` or `hash`, it works by providing reference,

you can read in brief [HERE](https://robertheaton.com/2014/07/22/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value/),

and you can have simple example as below,

```
ar1 = [23]
# => [23] 
ar2 = ar1
# => [23] 
ar2 << 34
# => [23, 34] 
ar1
# => [23, 34]
```

You can avoid this behaviour by creating new object by `new` keyword rather than passing reference of existing enumerable object.